# NameError uninitialized constant Worker - (production only) But others workers process with no error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I'm getting an NameError uninitialized constant error on production.  The call to the worker is in a name spaced controller (controllers/api/mobile).

However, I have a separate worker that has no issues on production and doesn't raise this error.

I have two workers:

`app/workers/ExtractionWorker`

`app/workers/CopyWasabiObject`

I have two controllers:

`app/controllers/photos_controller.rb`
`app/controllers/api/mobile/photos_controller.rb`

The non name spaced controller makes a call to `ExtractionWorker` with no problems and performs the work and doesn't raise this error.

When an API request is sent to the `api/mobile/photos_controller.rb`, I get the following error:

`NameError: uninitialized constant CopyWasabiObject`

From the command line on production, I can instantiate the class with no issue

```
Loading production environment (Rails 6.0.2.1)
irb(main):001:0> CopyWasabiObject.new
=> #<CopyWasabiObject:0x0000557aa6e262f8>
```

app/controllers/photos_controller.rb

```
if @photo.save
  ExtractionWorker.perform_async(wasabi_path(folder.uuid, photo_params[:name]), @photo.id)
  ...
end
```

works as expected

app/controllers/api/mobile/photos_controller.rb

```
def update
  ...
  CopyWasabiObject.perform_async(@photo.uuid, raw_folder_uuid) if @photo.update!(merged_params)
end
```

works on dev but fails on production

Why does one worker work, while the other fails to load?  I haven't touched auto loading in config/application.rb.  Every file is under app/* and I am not using anything at the root like lib.

What I have tried recently and doesn't work.
I tried name spacing the works to match the paths.  IE:  workers/api/mobile
I tried moving all works into app/models/
I have changed the calls in the controllers to call class methods which then call the worker

No matter what I seem to try, I just get the NameError: uninitialized constant CopyWasabiObject

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try calling it like `::CopyWasabiObject`

Comment: @PGill I tried that.  I should add that to the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think something is wrong with my systemd configuration.  I don't think sidekiq is being restarted on deploys.  I restarted sidekiq and everything was fine.